# Making ListView Scrolling Smooth

Tags: android, design-patterns

I am exploring the Android developer website and reading some articles. There is one way of defering loading of images in a list view using AsyncTask:

```
// Using an AsyncTask to load the slow images in a background thread
new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
    private ViewHolder v;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        v = params[0];
        return mFakeImageLoader.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (v.position == position) {
            // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
            // progress and set and show the image
            v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.icon.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}.execute(holder);
```

However, to me, there seems to be a little issue with that code. Say we load the images from the Internet and they each take a couple of seconds to load.

As a user, if we scroll the list and then switch to another activity, there are going to be some AsyncTasks running in the background and taking some bandwidth whereas we could need it in our new foreground activity.

How do you usually handle that case using their approach? Do you kill the AsyncTask associated to a holder when recycling the view? Do you keep track in the adapter of which AsyncTasks are still running and cancel them all when activity is stopping? Some other way of doing it?

My question is mainly about architecturing cleaning the pieces to solve that problem (not so much the implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that most time the downloads does not take enough time for this to become a problem, but if it does you should kill them. Also in their implementation they download an image and check to see if the view has been reused. If you have long delays you should cancel the task when you reuse. Note that the order of execution of the tasks differ between Android versions. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: Taken separatly, downloads could take a second, but if you got a list or grid of 100 items... Do you download only when the items get displayed? What if you are flinging?

Comment: There can be all kinds of variations depending on the requirements. One interesting sample that you should take a look at is: http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/development/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.java Where no loading is done while scrolling. You could of course also cache the data in a background thread (probably contained in a service), either to flash or ram. There is also the LruCache (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html) that can be of interest for these kinds of problems.